# Table AppUserRoles using Asp.Net Identity in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

I use code first and Asp.Net Identity

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder){
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(i => new { i.UserId, i.RoleId }).ToTable("AppUserRoles");
}
```

In IdentityUserRole Just have 2 entity Userd and RoleId
When i update-database it generate to table AppUserRoles

[image]
What the colunm AppUser_Id mean in table?
And How can i add Id in AppUser_Id because when AppUser_Id is null i can't get role of this user

Comment: Looks like you subclassed IdentityRole with your own application specific subclass IdentityUserRole? Those properties have been added to built in properties (UserId and RoleId) for IdentityRole

Comment: How i can Add Id to AppUser_Id when create new User ? it always  is null then i cant get role of user i create if is null